# How to bind Xamarin.Forms Entry to a Non String Type such as Decimal

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have and Entry created and I am trying to bind it to a Decimal property like such:

```cs
var downPayment = new Entry () {
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    Placeholder = "Down Payment",
    Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric
};
downPayment.SetBinding (Entry.TextProperty, "DownPayment");
```

I am getting the following error when I try to type into the Entry on the simulator.

> Object type System.String cannot be converted to target type: System.Decimal

Comment: Note: this should now work out of the box in version 1.2.1 and above

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At the time of this writing, there are no built-in conversion at binding time (but this is worked on), so the binding system does not know how to convert your `DownPayment` field (a decimal) to the `Entry.Text` (a string).

If `OneWay` binding is what you expect, a string converter will do the job. This would work well for a `Label`:

```cs
downPayment.SetBinding (Entry.TextProperty, new Binding ("DownPayment", stringFormat: "{0}"));
```

For an `Entry`, you expect the binding to work in both direction, so for that you need a converter:

```cs
public class DecimalConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is decimal)
            return value.ToString ();
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        decimal dec;
        if (decimal.TryParse (value as string, out dec))
            return dec;
        return value;
    }
}
```

and you can now use an instance of that converter in your Binding:

```cs
downPayment.SetBinding (Entry.TextProperty, new Binding ("DownPayment", converter: new DecimalConverter()));
```

**NOTE:**

OP's code should work out of the box in version 1.2.1 and above (from Stephane's comment on the Question). This is a workaround for versions lower than 1.2.1

Comment: this simple converter breaks down if you try to enter a decimal point

Comment: @codeConcussion It's all up to you. If you use the converter to convert user entries, this is probably fine as you expect the user and the app current culture to be the same. Now, if you expect values with an US formatting, you can use `TryParse (value as string, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out dec)` and a similar trick on `ToString ()`

Comment: @Stephane Sorry for being unclear. The issue isn't the decimal point, the issue in Xaramin is that the binding fires for every keystroke (there's no UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus like there is in WPF, AFAIK). So if you want to enter "1.23", you type "1" (works fine), then "." ("1." parses fine but the converter strips off the decimal). So to enter "1.23" I have to enter "123", then go back and put in the decimal.

Comment: oh, good catch ! use a OneWayToSource binding to avoid this, or implement your viewModel in a way that they do not trigger PropertyChanged if the value wasn't changed, as in https://gist.github.com/StephaneDelcroix/34e397fd908aa1826f66 .