# What is the function of Message sender in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

What is the function of Message sender in xamarin.forms? In my app I have cart contain list view and a Grant Total label. Is it possible to update the label using message sender? I can get the total amount from my sqlite db I need to update it to the view.

This is my number picker index change event in view cell

```cs
numPicker.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
    //  var price = _cartQuery.GetSum();
    sender = BindingContext;
    //    cm_items item = (cm_items)sender;
    if(Int32.Parse(btn_NumBtn.Text)<=1)
    {
        lbl_Price.Text = ((numPicker.SelectedIndex + 1) * (Int32.Parse(lbl_Price.Text))).ToString();
        btn_NumBtn.Text = (numPicker.SelectedIndex + 1).ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        int a = Int32.Parse(lbl_Price.Text);
        int b = Int32.Parse(btn_NumBtn.Text);
        int c = a / b;
        lbl_Price.Text = ((numPicker.SelectedIndex + 1) * c).ToString();
        btn_NumBtn.Text = (numPicker.SelectedIndex + 1).ToString();
    }
    _cartQuery.UpdatePicker((BindingContext as CartDB).Cart_Item_Id, numPicker.SelectedIndex + 1, Int32.Parse(lbl_Price.Text));
    price = _cartQuery.GetSum();
    //  App.Instance.ViewModel.TotalAmount = price;
    //   _cartDB.total = App.Instance.ViewModel.TotalAmount;
    Calculate_price();

    numPicker.IsEnabled = false;
};
```

Calculate_price method

```cs
public double Calculate_price()
{
    try
    {
        var price = 0;
        price = _cartQuery.GetSum();
        App.Instance.ViewModel.TotalAmount = price;
        return price;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

In my view i have a label named grant total, i need to update the total on  e number picker change

```cs
Label lbl_amnt = new Label
{
    //  Text = viewModel.Price.ToString(),
    // Text=CartCell.price.ToString(),
    Text = price.ToString(),
    FontSize = 18,
    FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
    TextColor = Color.FromRgb(102, 204, 102),
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
};
lbl_amnt.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "TotalAmount");
```

**update to my post as per the comment from @Grish**

In my view model i have this TotalAmount as a property

```cs
public double _TotalAmount;
public double TotalAmount
{
    get { return _TotalAmount; }
    set { _TotalAmount = value; OnPropertyChanged("TotalAmount");}
}
```

I think the better solution is i notify but the thing is view is not binding

Comment: Generally, using data binding is the "right" way to update a view in Xamarin.Forms. You need to bind Text property of the label in your view to some property of your viewmodel and then when you update viewmodel's property from sqlite, the text will be updated. You probably can manage this with message subscriptions, but I think it will mess your code and anyway, this is not a recommended way

Comment: @Grisha I have updated my post please have a look ,i think  i can use i notify for this  problem . But view is not updating. or is it possible to use a message sender for this solution ?

Comment: What is the definition of TotalAmount property in your ViewModel? Is it property or field? Does it have OnPropertyChanged call inside it?

Comment: If it is easier and quick solution, you can use the messaging center https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/messaging-center/

Comment: Total Amount is a property  i have OnPropertyChanged , i can see i have been update my post @Grisha

Answer (score 0):

Binding is definitely the answer in your case. I think the problem is that you bind `string` (label's text) to property of type `double`.
You should specify `IValueConverter` or `stringFormat` parameters in your call to `SetBinding`.
Check this link:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19146/binding-to-integers

Comment: thanks for your answer @Grisha  so i need to convert the double to string for binding to the view like this

  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442617/how-to-bind-xamarin-forms-entry-to-a-non-string-type-such-as-decimal

Comment: Exactly! I think this will do.

Comment: I have a doubt . This my view model, should i need to add anything more inside my view model ?. This class contain TotalAmount property
 
`public BaseViewModel() { // CartCell objcartcell = new CartCell(); App.Instance.ViewModel = this; TempList = TempList ?? new ObservableCollection<cm_items>(); this.Title = AppResources.AppResource.Cart_menu_title; }`

Comment: This is only a constructor... It looks OK to me. I don't know whether you have some additional logic to add there. I'm sorry, but probably I don't understand your question... You need to make sure you implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface in your BaseViewModel class (or derive your class from some class that implements it). But this has nothing to do with the code of your constructor.